# My current iptable configuration doesn't work CentOS 6, clean install [FIXED]

Tags: iptables

This is working now.

```
### Login as Super User
su

chkconfig iptables off
/etc/init.d/iptables on

### Clear/flush iptables
iptables -F 
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT 
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT 
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

### Allow SSH
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

### Allow YUM updates
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 --match owner --uid-owner 0 --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 --match owner --uid-owner 0 --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

### Add your rules form the link above, here
# ftp,smtp,imap,http,https,pop3,imaps,pop3s
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,25,143,80,443,110,993,995 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 21,25,143,80,110,443,993,995 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

## allow dns
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -o eth0 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT && iptables -A INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

# handling pings
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT && iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT && iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

# manage ddos attacks
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT

## Implement some logging so that we know what's getting dropped
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP

# once a rule affects traffic then it is no longer managed
# so if the traffic has not been accepted, block it
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

# allow only internal port forwarding
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# create an iptables config file
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules

### Append the following to the rc.local file
#nano /etc/rc.local
####---
#/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
####---

/etc/init.d/iptables save
## check to see if this setting is working great.
service iptables restart
## log out/in testing
chkconfig iptables on
```

What is the problem with this setup?
If I restart the server it doesn't allow me back in SSH, and there may be a problem with Yum
CentOS 6

I modified the above from: https://gist.github.com/Jonathonbyrd/1274837#file-instructions
I'm trying to secure a magento install on nginx

I've installed php5.4, Percona Server(MySQL drop in replacement), Nginx, apc, zenopcode, ioncube.  I've got everything working except for the iptables.

Comment: Which distro are you using ? It's really not clear what you've done here or what your expectations are. Is this a series of instructions you followed or is it a script you have created. If he former then whilst carrying out the operations did you encounter any errors - if so what where they ? If the later then it's never going to work.

Comment: I'm running CentOS 6.

Comment: And the rest of my questions ?

Comment: Just fixed it.  removed sudo, logged in as SU.

Answer (score 1):

You're lacking a sudo there...

```
### Allow SSH
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't that.  I forgot to add sudo to those lines in serverfault not in the actual file.